# Is it possible to edit text content only by using CSS properties?

Tags: css, text, edit

I'm forced to use a website that had too many distracting elements and I'm trying to adjust it using custom CSS. I stumbled upon this wonderful navigation links:

```
______Link#1__________
______Link#2__________
```

Can I remove those _'s only by using CSS properties that currently work in latest stable version of FF?

Comment: Alternately: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Alternately 2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet (but also a JavaScript approach, thus not an *answer* to a CSS question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the links are similar in width, you could hide the offending underscores out of view through overflow: hidden:

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -45px
}
```

If they do have different widths, you could target each one individually through the nth-of-type selector...

```
ul.nav li:nth-of-type(3) a {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -45px
}
```

It's an interesting challenge, good luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/F24rh/

Answer (score 1):

No; You can currently only add text before and after elements using CSS (and even that support is limited).

To do what you're attempting, consider writing a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: Yeah thought so, but I haven't been keeping up with CSS progress lately so I figgured I'd ask. Thanks for tip, GM will do.